# error while converting sql to eloquent query

Tags: mysql, php

I have converted an `sql query` to `eloquent` like below:

```
$roomtypes = DB::select(`rt.id`,`rt.type`,`rt.total_no_of_rooms`)
    ->addSelect(DB::raw(`SUM(r.no_of_rooms) as reserved rooms`))
    ->selectSub(`rt.total_no_of_rooms`, `rooms available`)
    ->selectSub(`-`, `rooms available`)
    ->selectSub(`SUM`, `rooms available`)
    ->from(`Roomtypes as rt`)
    ->join(`Reservations as r`, function($join) {
        $join->on(`r.roomtype_id`, `=`, `rt.id`)
            ->on(`$check_in`, `>=`, `r.check_in`)
            ->on(`$check_out`, `<=`, `r.check_out`);
        })
    ->groupBy(`rt.id`)
    ->groupBy(`rt.type`)
    ->groupBy(`rt.total_no_of_rooms`)
    ->get();
```

but I am getting an error

> "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, null given, called in "

Please, could anyone help ?

Comment: What is the value of $check_in? null? It sounds like it's supposed to be an array , presumably with only one element / value.

Comment: Can you please "strip out" the PHP code and run the "pure" SQL on the mysql CLI. If that fails, then it's a problem for here. If it works but fails on the PHP, then it's for guys over on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the an alternate for this. I created a stored procedure in laravel using migrations

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProcedure extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        DB::unprepared('
            CREATE PROCEDURE fetch_all_users()
            BEGIN
                select * from users;
            END'
        );
    }

```
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    DB::unprepared('DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fetch_all_users');
}
```

}

Then i called it in the code:

> DB::select('call fetch_all_users()')

Answer (score 0):

in this line

```
->join(`Reservations as r`, function($join) {
```

you need to add to the query function the parent variables for use,
here

```
->on(`$check_in`, `>=`, `r.check_in`)
->on(`$check_out`, `<=`, `r.check_out`);
```

you are using 2 variables of a parent fucntion change to

```
->join(`Reservations as r`, function($join) use ($check_in,$check_out){
```

so you can use the 2 variables inside the function